# Finding all primes $p$ such that $3p+20$ and $p+20 $ are primes

Tags: number-theory

I need to find all primes $p$ such that $3p+20$ and $p+20 $ are primes.

The first primes which satisfy the condition are: $3, 11, 17, 23$. I've tried to find the dependence, and found that $p \equiv 5(mod6) $ for $p > 3$. Is it correct and how to prove it?

Comment: Note that if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ then $p+20$ is divisible by $3$ and therefore not prime. So $p\equiv 2\pmod 3$, and it cannot be $\equiv 2\pmod{6}$, so it is congruent to $5$ modulo $6$.  But $p\equiv 5\pmod{6}$ is clearly not a *sufficient* condition, take $p=29$.

Comment: @AlexeyTsymbal If you _need_ to find all such primes $p$, then it will take you a long time... Standard conjectures imply that there are infinitely many, but no one has proved this.  Thus it is difficult to give any more transparent description than the one in the title.

Comment: @ErickWong, I need to find all such primes, but I suppose there's a way to find the common form of such number rather than list all of them

Comment: @AlexeyTsymbal Nope, no such thing.  There could be infinitely many; there could be finitely many.  No one knows for sure (with proof, that is).  Given this state of affairs, what type of "common form" can you possibly hope to find?  Is there any evidence that leads you to believe it exists?  It certainly won't be something like $f(n)$ for some concisely-defined function $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at prime $p>3$, we can see that for prime $p+20$, since $20 \equiv 2 \bmod 3$  we also need that $p\equiv 2 \bmod 3$, so to make $p$ odd, we need $p \equiv 5 \bmod 6$. The prime $3p+20$ does not impose any extra requirements to bases $2$ or $3$.

However, while this condition is necessary, it is not sufficient.

For bases above $5$, there will be two excluded values from the two conditions as $p$ gets big enough to make them relevant. So considering  modulo $7$, for example, we cannot have $p \equiv \{1,5\} \bmod 7$; similarly, we cannot have $p \equiv \{2,8\} \bmod 11$ or $p \equiv \{6,2\} \bmod 13$ etc.

So there is no overarching single condition to test; it is still a sieving process.